# Open Source solution for MongoDB Community auditing

Tags: mongodb, security, audit

I know the MongoDB Enterprise Edition has auditing capability, I was wondering if there any sort of open source solution or any roll-your-own solutions to auditing collection level changes.

Answer (score 3):

[Percona](https://www.percona.com/software/mongo-database/percona-server-for-mongodb) community server available for mongoDB auditing but I'm not sure will it do collection level auditing. [studio 3T](https://studio3t.com/)  support collection level auditing and you can export to word also. It's enterprise edition but you can use 14 days trail and 14 more days extend.